# C# SharpDevelop The command “copy” [FILEDIRECTORY.dll] exited with code 1

Tags: c#, dll, compiler-errors, console

So, I'm opening C# source code in SharpDevelop and when I try to compile my code, it always throws this error: C# SharpDevelop The command “copy” [FILEDIRECTORY.dll] exited with code 1

The DLLs are fine and aren't blocked or anything on my PC, they aren't in use. None of the file directories have spaces in their names. I tried moving it to a different directory closer to the C drive but nothing works. How do I fix this?

I don't know where in my code it is executing this because it won't take me to the error when I double click it.